# benchRun query with projection

Tags: mongodb, benchmarking

I want to benchmark some queries using [benchRun](http://www.mongodb.org/about/contributors/js-benchmarking-harness/). But I don't see an option for [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/).

Say I wanted to do the following query `find({_id:1},{children:0})` how do I construct the operation document to reflect that?
Or doesn't projection make sense in a benchmark scenario?

The documentation says:

> **update**
>   The update object (same as 2nd argument of update() function).

So I was thinking I could do something like:

```
ops = [
    {op: "find", ns: t.getFullName(), query: {_id:1}, update: {children:0}}
]
```

It doesn't fail, but not sure if it actually does anything.

Comment: Normally it doesn't make sense since projection should be a small operation on your db and if it isn't then you have a design problem, however, maybe there is a undocumented `project` or `projection` option too? If not then I dunno

Comment: @Sammaye good advice! I looked at the src and managed to find a `filter` option. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/scripting/bench.cpp#L436

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an undocumented option (actually there are more) called `filter`. See [GitHub src](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/scripting/bench.cpp#L436) for further info.

The solution:

```
ops = [
    {op: "find", ns: t.getFullName(), query: {_id:1}, filter: {children:0}}
]
```